# How to escape a NSString from regex characters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I'd like to check whether a user-input NSString match the end part of another NSString, expected result:

```
User input    To match         Result 
----------    -------------    ------
  ing         Good morning      True
  mor         Good morning      False (as mor is not at end of string)
  ing$        Good morning      False (as $ should not be treated as a regex char)
```

So the following code works:

```
NSString *source;
NSString *input;
NSString *pattern;
NSRange range;

source = @"Good morning";
input = @"ing";
pattern = [input stringByAppendingString:@"$"];
range = [source rangeOfString:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@", source, pattern, NSStringFromRange(range));

-> Good morning, ing$, {9, 3}
```

until the user inputs `ing$`:

```
input = @"ing$";
pattern = [input stringByAppendingString:@"$"];
range = [source rangeOfString:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@", source, pattern, NSStringFromRange(range));

-> Good morning, ing$$, {9, 3}
```

The question is, how can I escape the `input` such that user-input characters are not treated as regex characters?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape all regex characters like below way -

user input - ing$ need to convert ing\$?